# InnoDB Failing to start / MySQL not loading plugins

Tags: mysql, linux

I installed MariaDB on my system (Debian 9), however, upon running `sudo service mysql start`, I get these errors:

```
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.5-MariaDB-1:10.5.5+maria~stretch) starting as process 30151 ...
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32184)
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea mariadbd[30151]: 2020-09-22 12:32:37 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 22 12:32:37 bremea systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.5 database server.
```

I assume this is an error with InnoDB, but I may be wrong. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling mysql but that didn't work either. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like the ibdata1 file might be corrupted; restored it from a recent backup, which you undoubtedly have handy.

Comment: Given mysql.plugin isn't a innodb stable and this is a fresh installation I'd suspect a storage reliability error or out of space during installation. If you've got  no data you can `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*; mysql_install_db -u mysql; systemctl start mariadb.service`

Comment: test your storage and/or space. Look in `dmesg`(command) output for evidence of hardware errors.

Comment: Was fixed by removing everything and reinstalling mysql. No idea what happened.